# Swift one out of three segue is not passing data

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass data to another controller with a segue after clicking on a button.

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func agilityDogBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {
        let course = objs[0]
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DogAgilitySegue", sender: course)
    }
}
@IBAction func baseEducationBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {
        let course = objs[1]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BaseEducationSegue", sender: course)
    }
}
@IBAction func puppyBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {
        let course = objs[2]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PuppyClassSegue", sender: course)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DogAgilitySegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ClassDetailsVC {
            if let course = sender as? Course {
                destination.course = course
            }
        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "PuppyClassSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ClassDetailsVC {
            if let course = sender as? Course {
                destination.course = course
            }
        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "BaseEducationSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ClassDetailsVC {
            if let course = sender as? Course {
                destination.course = course
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the first two segues are working perfectly fine.
The third one (PuppyClassSegue) is not passing the data through.
It opens the page but the data are not showing, basically the `destination.course` is not happening.

Any idea how is that possible?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the `prepare(for:sender:)` method to see if it gets to the line that sets `destination.course`? That might provide some more insight into what is happening.

Comment: I've put the break line and it gets there...

Comment: And what is the value of the `course` variable on that line?

Comment: There must be something wrong with objs[2], because they all initialize the same VC, so course in the VC also declared correctly I suppose. Investigate your object at objs[2]

Comment: I have added a screeshot.. My objs[2] is showned if i put it inside another segue...

Comment: I cannot find anything wrong with this code. Are you sure that `destination.course` is not being set? Perhaps the problem lies in the `ClassDetailsVC` class. Also, it might have something to do with it being an `NSManagedObject`, but I do not know enough about to Core Data to judge on that.

Comment: Not sure either... everything seemed to be ok since they all works except this one... anyway the solution suggested by Sh_Khan seems to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that course is `nil` , also you can do this by hooking all buttons to the same action and setting tags for them 0,1,2 respectively

```
@IBAction func agilityDogBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {
        let course = objs[sender.tag]
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueFromCon", sender: course)
} 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ClassDetailsVC {
            if let course = sender as? Course {
                print("hit here ",course)
                destination.course = course
            }
        }
}
```

make 1 segue named say `SegueFromCon` from the current vc to the detailsVC

Comment: But is not nil with the other two segues... it works fine... is just the PuppyClassSegue which is not passing data... and the code is the same...

Comment: Sorry..I'm not sure i have understand. I need 3 different segues because i have 3 different buttons. it gets to the prepare for segue and if i print course.title it actually print it. So it is not nil it's just not passing through...

Comment: no need to create a segue for each button , make it from the vc itself the top yellow icon

Comment: Course doesn't necessarily have to be `nil`. Also, I would not use view tags like this. It makes the code harder to understand, and stores data in the view which doesn't belong there.

Comment: i'm a total beginner... :)

Comment: @Marco your problem is hooking segues to the buttons remove all , set tags for the buttons , then drag the segue from the yellow rounded circle in top to the detailsvc and set the segue name then replace your code with above only

Comment: @Sh_Khan: Using one method with view tags is not going to fix the problem. It's just going to make the code harder to read by abusing view tags.

Comment: @wvteijlingen i would prefer using it instead of having 3 same methods

Comment: Thank you!!! i'm not sure to understand what was wrong with my previous code (apart being formatted not well...)... but the solution you suggested works fine... and it's definitely better formatted.... Thank you!

Comment: @Sh_Khan: Yeah, having 3 duplicate methods is not ideal. But imho the proper solution would be to extract the duplicate code into a new method, or to introduce a new property to a UIButton subclass that conveys meaning, unlike `tag`.

Comment: @wvteijlingen , using tags isn't wrong and if it is , then no meaning for creating this property by Apple , also it needs some level of professionalism to realize that but it's not hard to